# 'int?' does not contain a definition for 'TryFormat'

Tags: c#, nullable

I am having a hard time understanding how nullable value types works in C#9.

Following documentation from:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

I can write (no compiler error):

```
int? a = 10;
a++; // No need for explicit 'a.Value'
```

But I *cannot* write (compiler error):

```
Span<char> TryFormatOrNull(int? input)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[512];
    if (input == null) return null;
    _ = input.TryFormat(buffer, out _);
    return buffer;
}
```

I need to write (no syntaxic sugar):

```
Span<char> TryFormatOrNull(int? input)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[512];
    if (input == null) return null;
    _ = input.Value.TryFormat(buffer, out _);
    return buffer;
}
```

What did I misunderstood with nullable value types vs member function/operator ?

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't need the `!` in the second version, as the compiler should "know" that it's not null by that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What did I misunderstood with nullable value types vs member function/operator ?

That operators are automatically "lifted" (i.e. the operators for the non-nullable value type are automatically made available for the corresponding nullable value type) but methods aren't. That's all, really.

See [section 12.4.8 of the C# standard](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#1248-lifted-operators) for details of lifted operators, and [11.6.2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/conversions.md#1162-lifted-conversions) for lifted conversions.

Comment: I am guessing there is a good reason for this. Do you know why ?

Comment: @malat: Aside from anything else, the designers know that `Nullable<T>` doesn't have any operators defined on it directly - but it *does* have methods. If the non-nullable T declared some methods that were also on `Nullable<T>`, that could be really confusing. Additionally, the behavior of the operators is pretty easy to specify in terms of what happens if the value is null - that's not the case for methods (where there can be out parameters etc).

Comment: @malat If it worked that way, would `someNullableInt.GetType()` return `Nullable<int>` or `int`?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `++` is a predefined unary operator which can be ["lifted"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators) (while `TryFormat` method is not):

> The predefined unary and binary operators or any overloaded operators that are supported by a value type `T` are also supported by the corresponding nullable value type `T?`. These operators, also known as *lifted operators*, produce `null` if one or both operands are `null`; otherwise, the operator uses the contained values of its operands to calculate the result.